# Noisy notifications from the Android app on Android 5.0

Tags: bug, android-app, audio

Starting with Android 5 Lollipop (on my Nexus 7), I can't silence notifications from the Stack Exchange app without turning off sound completely, which also disables alarms.

If I understand [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/90133/31016) on the Android site correctly, the problem is that the app uses the "media" channel rather than the "notification" channel for notifications.

The specific problem I'm having is that I have notifications from the app enabled, with the default sound. When I put the tablet into "Priority interruptions only" mode (which disables audible notifications for events, reminders, and messages), I still get audible notifications. Setting the tablet to "No interruptions" is not a solution, since I use it as an alarm clock.

As a workaround, I've set "Sound" to "Silent" in the app settings. This should avoid audible notifications while I'm trying to sleep, but I actually want audible notifications during the day.

Comment: When you get to 5.1, Silent mode would be an option -- see http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/02/24/android-5-1-feature-spotlight-volume-interruptions-menu-adds-next-alarm-new-option/.

Comment: Are you getting notifications at all from your app? Since I've moved to a new phone with Lollipop, I haven't gotten any notifications through the app since. Everything stock.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I'm getting *some* notifications, but I'm not sure I'm getting all the notifications I'm supposed to. I actually haven't been paying much attention lately. (I still have "Sound" set to "Silent" in the app's settings.) I've changed my mind about wanting audible notifications from the app during the day, so this isn't really much of a problem for me anymore.

Comment: Is this still an issue?  There's nothing obvious we're doing wrong since we play the sound through the standard `NotificationCompat.Builder.setSound` API.

Comment: @BrianNickel: I don't *think* so. I'm on Marshmallow now, with notifications enabled, and it at least hasn't been particularly annoying. I'll play with it and follow up later.